# Force the origin to start at 0

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axes

How can I set the origin / interception of the y-axis and x-axis in ggplot2?

The line of the x-axis should be exactly at `y=Z`.

With `Z=0` or another given value.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

`xlim` and `ylim` don't cut it here. You need to use `expand_limits`, `scale_x_continuous`, and `scale_y_continuous`. Try:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p <- p + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0)
p # not what you are looking for
```

[image]

```
p + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

You may need to adjust things a little to make sure points are not getting cut off (see, for example, the point at `x = 5` and `y = 5`.

Comment: I also needed to specify limits: `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,5))`, somehow without it it didn't work

Comment: I think one more piece can be helpful, which is using something like `expand=expand_scale(mult=c(0,0.1))` so you still get the padding at the upper ends: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056123/8400969

Answer (score 39):

Simply add these to your ggplot:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))
```

#### Example

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p <- p + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0)
p # not what you are looking for


p + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,NA)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

Lastly, **take *great* care not to unintentionally exclude data off your chart**. For example, a `position = 'dodge'` could cause a bar to get left off the chart entirely (e.g. if its value is zero and you start the axis at zero), so you may not see it and may not even know it's there. I recommend plotting data in full first, inspect, then use the above tip to improve the plot's aesthetics.

Comment: is it also possible to build this into a new ggplot theme?

Comment: @Bolle I’m not sure, but interested to find out as well, you could ask as a separate question and link to here

Comment: Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61969752/5783745) for future reference

Comment: Best answer imo for showing the necessity to include `limits`.

Comment: based on my experience, the benefit of adding `limits=c(0,NA)` is that makes "0" appear on the axis labels. Without it, the plot area will include 0, but zero generally doesn't appear on the axis labels

Comment: Using `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))` affected the upper limit of my graph. I had more success with simply `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA))`

Answer (score 7):

In the latest version of ggplot2, this can be more easy.

```r
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point()
p+ geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0))) + scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0)))
```

[image]

See `?expansion()` for more details.

Comment: This only changes padding around data points, but does not help set axes origin to zero or other desired value.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is using [`coord_cartesian`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html) with `expand = FALSE`. The limits are taken from the data or based on your limits. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p <- p + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0)
p + coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You could also specify the limits in `coord_cartesian` directly like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p + coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, xlim = c(0, NA), ylim = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>