# Removing negative plot area in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How can I remove the plot area below the x and y axis in ggplot2 (see example below). I have tried several of the theme elements (panel.border, panel.margin, plot.margin) without any luck.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg,xmin=0,ymin=0)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Is something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13701732/1270695) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 9):

Use the `expand` argument in continuous scale aesthetics...

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg,xmin=0,ymin=0)) +
geom_point()+
scale_x_continuous( expand = c(0,0) , limits = c(0,6) )+
scale_y_continuous( expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,35) )
```

Set limits to avoid extreme values being cut off.
[image]

but in case you wanted no margin around the entire plot, you need to use the `theme` element, `plot.margin`, like so (notice in the plot below the extreme right edge is cut to zero)..

```
require(grid) # for unit
p + theme( plot.margin = unit( c(0,0,0,0) , "in" ) )
```

[image]

Comment: @Simon0101, If that's the answer, then I'm going to vote to close the question as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701347/force-the-origin-to-start-at-0-in-ggplot2-r) especially since the other question is much more explicit than "remove negative plot area".... Still waiting for the OP to clarify though...

Comment: Hmmm..maybe keep this entry after all since now it is more informative than the existing entry

Comment: I agree, if that is what you are after, because the latter is not answered in the linked question. Maybe you should retract your own clsoe vote! :-) Cheers!