# ggsurvplot - axes crossing at 0,0

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

`Survminer` produces nice plots, but is there a way to further change the outcome with regular `ggplot`-commands?

What I try to do is make the y-axis start in the origin, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701347/force-the-origin-to-start-at-0-in-ggplot2-r).
For a regular ggplot, this works perfectly, but I can't make it work with survminer:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

df<-genfan
df$treat<-sample(c(0,1),nrow(df),replace=TRUE)


fit <- survfit(Surv(hours, status) ~ treat,
               data = df)

p<-ggsurvplot(fit, data = df, risk.table = TRUE,,ncensor.plot=FALSE,tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
              ggtheme = theme_survminer(font.legend=c(12,"bold","black") ))


p%+%scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))%+%scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

This produces an error

> "Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale."

and an additional error

> "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Is there some way around this?

Comment: How do we get `genfan`?  The first message is a warning, not an error.  The second message has to do with the `risk table = TRUE`, which appears to make a second plot that has a discrete y axis instead of a continuous y axis, which leads to the error.

Comment: @aosmith `genfan` is a dataset available in the `survival` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibile solution to your problem is to modify the `ggsurvplot` and `ggrisktable` inserting the `expand=c(0,0)` in the proper place.
At this [link](https://pastebin.com/rNwRHBzE) you can find my proposal. 
Click on "download" and save the file `a_modified_ggsurvplot.txt` in your working directory.
Then run the following code:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

df <- genfan
df$treat <- sample(c(0,1),nrow(df),replace=TRUE)
fit <- survfit(Surv(hours, status) ~ treat, data = df)

source("a_modified_ggsurvplot.txt")
p <- myggsurvplot(fit, data = df, risk.table = TRUE,
     ncensor.plot=FALSE,tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
     ggtheme = theme_survminer(font.legend=c(12,"bold","black")))
print(p)
```

Here is the plot:
[image]

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 2):

It is 2023 now and in the meantime a similar solution has been implemented into ggsurvplot itself: you can just specify `axes.offset = F` in the `ggsurvplot` call, so also no need to name it p (or anything else).