# ggsurvplot is it possible to start graph at (0,0)

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival

I would like to have the axis crossing at 0,0 in ggsurvplot. There is a similar older question here [ggsurvplot - axes crossing at 0,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024907/ggsurvplot-axes-crossing-at-0-0). However, I am having errors with this method.

First error due to adding confidence intervals `conf.int = T`:

`Error in ggpubr::geom_exec(.geom_confint, data = d, ymin = "lower", ymax = "upper",  :  object '.geom_confint' not found`

Second error occurs when adding median survival lines `surv.median.line = "hv"`:

`Error in .add_surv_median(p, fit, type = surv.median.line, fun = fun,  :  could not find function ".add_surv_median"`

Is there another way to solve this?

`ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)`

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right then you could achieve your desired result by removing the default expansion via `scale_x/y_continuous` like so:

```r
library(survminer)
library(survival)

fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

p <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)

p$plot <- p$plot + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0))

p
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Can I manipulate the survival plot by doing this as if it was a ggplot ?

Comment: Yep. You only have to take into account that a `ggsurvplot` object is basically a list where the `ggplot` object is stored as an element with name ´plot`.