# Error bar does not start from 0 origin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to start from 0 origin but unfortunately I can not fix the problem. Any solution? I have already tried `expand_limits` and `xlim` but they did not work.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force the origin to start at 0 in ggplot2 (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701347/force-the-origin-to-start-at-0-in-ggplot2-r)

Comment: Can you include the code you used & elaborate on your question? Going purely on the chart you posted, both x & y axis include 0 in their respective ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `scale_x_continuous`.

If you have plotted your graph and named it as `so.graph` for this example, then you'd need to add:

`so.graph + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))`.

You'll also need to add in some limits so the graph doesn't cut off any points - without knowing your values I can't suggest appropriate points, but this would look like:

`so.graph + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,20)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,20))`

Hope this helps!