# Force the origin to start at 0 without margin between data and x axis in new ggplot theme

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axes

Based on this question [Force the origin to start at 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701347/force-the-origin-to-start-at-0/61437896?noredirect=1#comment109603133_61437896) I want to implement this into a new created theme and not just as a default setting.

```
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)))
```

How can I do this without defining it every single plot?

[image: requested result]

Comment: It's an open issue in the ggplot2 issue tracker: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2691

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this not possible via `theme()`. But you can define a wrapper around `scale_y_continuous` like so

```
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)

scale_y_origin <- function(...) {
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)), ...)
}

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_origin()
```