# Plot in R: Gap beginning and end of the x-axis - how to remove?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, sjplot

That is my code

```
plot_model(mylogit, type = "pred", terms = c("ScoreEnvAtt [all]", "Guilt")) + 
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "Guilt"), labels = c("Low", "Medium", "High")) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "Guilt"), labels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"))  +
  labs( title = "",
        x = "Environmental Attitudes",
        y = "Probability of choosing the green investment") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)  + 
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size=12))
```

[image: And this is what I get]

How can I remove the two gaps such that the x axis starts at 3 and ends at 7?

Comment: Also highly appreciated if some pro here sees something that visually annoys in the plot and tells me how to make it better - I am using it for my thesis.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701347/force-the-origin-to-start-at-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force the origin to start at 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701347/force-the-origin-to-start-at-0)

Comment: @AdamQuek Ah yes that is the solution the others proposed below, thanks!!

Comment: @BappaDas I saw this posting before but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

sjPlot uses ggplot2 so you can find the options to modifying your plot by looking for ggplot2. In this case, what you need is expand=c(0,0) inside scale_x_continuous, for example:

```
library(sjPlot)
fit = lm(mpg ~ hp,data=mtcars)
plot_model(fit,typpe="pred") + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change your scale with the following addition to your ggplot:

```
 plot_model(mylogit, type = "pred", terms = c("ScoreEnvAtt [all]", "Guilt")) + 
 scale_colour_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "Guilt"), labels = c("Low", "Medium", "High")) + 
 scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "Guilt"), labels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"))  +
 labs( title = "",
    x = "Environmental Attitudes",
    y = "Probability of choosing the green investment") + theme_gray(base_size = 14) + 
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size=12)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3, 7), expand = c(0, 0))
```