# In R/ggplot2, when i use expand_limits, it seems can't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, I want to make bar_plot align with axis x (remove the blank area as attached image ). When  use `expand_limits(y=0)`, it seems can't work.Anyone can help ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
data <- data.frame(category=c("a","b","c","d"),value=4:1)
data %>% ggplot(aes(category,value,fill=category))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+scale_fill_brewer(palette='Greens',direction=-1)+
  expand_limits(y=0)
```

[image]

Comment: It's not `expand_limits` what you are looking for it's the `expand` argument, i.e. try with `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, .05, .05))`.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  How to understand the four parmateres for expand ? it seems no help file for expand.Thanks

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13701347/680068

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `expansion`:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(category=c("a","b","c","d"),value=4:1),  
       aes(category, value, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)))
```

[image]

With `mult = c(0, 0.05)`, this means that the bottom is not expanded (`0`) and the top is expanded 5% (which looks about like the default). If you set a length-1 arg `mult=0`, then both are set to the same (not expanded here). You can also use `add=` (same methodology) with or without `mult=`.